# SSRS - Only allow data to be entered into one parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report with 3 parameters. Problem is, I only want data to be entered into one of those parameters. If data is present in more than one parameters, I want the end user to get a warning message. The reason behind this is that, depending on what parameter has data, it creates a separate temp table to compile result data. If more than one is entered, it end up locking the SQL server. 
I'm on SQL 2008. How can I accomplish this?

Here are my parameters in ssrs:

[image]

...and here is my stored proc. If one of the parameters contains a value, a null value is passed to the other two parameters

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[uspS_SerialNumberLookupReport] @_SalesOrder AS VARCHAR(10) ='', @_AQNum AS VARCHAR(10) ='', @_Serial AS VARCHAR(10) =''
AS


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SerialNumberLookupReport') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #SerialNumberLookupReport

CREATE TABLE #SerialNumberLookupReport
(Company varchar(1),
 Serial varchar(15),
 StockCode varchar(30),
 Description varchar(50),
 SalesOrder int,
 OrderDate datetime,
 ReqShipDate datetime,
 CustomerPoNumber varchar(10),
 CustomerName varchar(50),
 ShippingInstrs varchar(50),
 ShippingCarrier varchar(50),
 ShippingLink varchar(1000))

INSERT INTO #SerialNumberLookupReport

EXEC uspS_SerialNumberLookupX @SalesOrder=@_SalesOrder, @AQNum=@_AQNum, @Serial=@_Serial

INSERT INTO #SerialNumberLookupReport

EXEC uspS_SerialNumberLookupE @SalesOrder=@_SalesOrder, @AQNum=@_AQNum, @Serial=@_Serial

SELECT DISTINCT
   Company
  ,Serial
  ,StockCode
  ,Description
  ,SalesOrder
  ,OrderDate
  ,ReqShipDate
  ,CustomerPoNumber
  ,CustomerName
  ,ShippingInstrs
  ,ShippingCarrier
  ,ShippingLink
 FROM #SerialNumberLookupReport
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use 2 parameters instead, like

[image]

to answer comment:
you could use your existing parameters as variables like:

```
 create proc some_stored_proc
(@id_type varchar(30) , @value varchar(50))
as

    declare 
    @SalesOrder varchar(50) null,
    @Serial varchar(50) null,
    @AQ varchar(50) null

    if @id_type = 'Sales Order#'
    set @SalesOrder = @value
    else 
    if @id_type = 'Serial#'
    set @Serial = @value
    else 
    if @id_type = 'AQ#'
    set @AQ = @value
```

Comment: Good idea. How would I edit my report and query for this approach? Right now it uses a proc with those 3 parameters.

Comment: i made an update, but i'm not sure if that approach will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried this and unfortunately it didn't work with passing values to my existing stored procedure.